# How can I configure logback conf to send all messages to stderr?

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

Recently added some println output to my program...
and now dont want logback INFO messages merging with them.
How can I get all messages to stderr ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create appender and attach all logs for it:

```
<appender name="STDERR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <target>System.err</target>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date [%thread] - 5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="org.apache" level="INFO ">
    <appender-ref ref="STDERR"/>
</logger>
```

All `org.apache` class logs(that uses slf4j) will be directed to `System.err`

Comment: I was doing it right... but it wasnt finding the proper logback.xml

Answer (score 9):

Use a `ConsoleAppender` with the `target` attribute set to `System.err`.  See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#ConsoleAppender for details.

Something like this in your logback.xml should work:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDERR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <target>System.err</target>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDERR" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is there a typo?  Should the appender-ref line near the end have STDERR instead of STDOUT?

Comment: Thanks, good catch.  My answer is essentially the same as the current accepted answer, except with the outer `<configuration>` tags.